# Issue with textbox display format in Jquery mobile

Tags: css, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, icons

I have a text box to enter a mobile number in application. There is an option that either enter a mobile number or pick from their contacts. So kept both text box and pick from contact button in same row. For that I have used control panel. It is getting displaying properly but text box is displaying little down as shown in image. I need that edges of both button and text box are equal.

code:

```
   <div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
     <input name="" id="numberTxt" placeholder="Enter A Mobile Number" value=""  type="tel">
      <a href="" id="iconshow" data-role="button" onClick='pickAContact()' data-icon="plus" data-iconpos="notext">Add</a>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.ui-controlgroup-controls {
                width: 100%;
                margin-bottom: 42px;
             }

            .ui-controlgroup-controls .ui-input-text{
                position: absolute;
                left: 15px;
                right: 73px;
                height: 40px;
            }

            .ui-controlgroup-controls a.ui-btn{
                position: absolute;
                right: 15px; left: auto;   
            }
```

It is really appreciate if anyone replace the plus icon with add contact icon. I have tried to add contact icon but i didn't succeed.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Just removed the margin for text box.

like,

```
.ui-controlgroup-controls .ui-input-text{
        position: absolute;

        left: 15px;
        right: 73px;
        height: 40px;
        margin:0;
    }
```

link,

http://jsfiddle.net/manjunath_r/tcaw6/4/

Answer (score 0):

### Change your css code to the following one:

**I did a little work with your CSS, hope it will work**

### try the link:

```
[Ans]: http://jsfiddle.net/topgun/s422Q/
```

### If it works don't forget to VOTE

## Thank you and all the best

Comment: can you add some current screen shots

Comment: screen shot is same. It does not change after css modification

Comment: Or else can you please help me that how to add contact icon instead plus icon

Comment: can you send your skype id

Comment: Can you add me its chinmoy.basak

Comment: Yes but all screen heights are not same right. instead of using top Is there any other way.. @Dron

Comment: try the link http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/25bZC/ it is not html5 but only html with css may be it will help you..